# Наследование и общие данные

Tags: javascript

[код в jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/wcL8dg5o/)

```js
class FirstClass {
  constructor() {
    this.flag = 'first class';
    this.label = document.querySelector('.class-val');
  }
  updateVal() {
    this.label.textContent = this.flag.toString();
  }
  toggle() {
    this.flag = !this.flag
    this.updateVal();
  }
}

class SecondClass extends FirstClass {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.updateVal();
  }
}

class ThirdClass extends SecondClass {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.label = document.querySelector('.class-val-2');
    console.log(this.flag);
    this.updateVal();
  }
  toggle() {
    this.flag = !this.flag;
    this.updateVal();
  }
  updateVal() {
    this.label.textContent = this.flag.toString();
  }
}

const secondClass = new SecondClass();
const thirdClass = new ThirdClass();
const updateBtn1 = document.querySelector('.js-update-val');
const updateBtn2 = document.querySelector('.js-update-val-2');
const toggleBtn1 = document.querySelector('.js-toggle-val');
const toggleBtn2 = document.querySelector('.js-toggle-val-2');

updateBtn1.addEventListener('click', () => {
  secondClass.updateVal();
})
updateBtn2.addEventListener('click', () => {
  thirdClass.updateVal();
})
toggleBtn1.addEventListener('click', () => {
  secondClass.toggle();
})
toggleBtn2.addEventListener('click', () => {
  thirdClass.toggle();
})
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.col {
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="class-val" data-id="1">Val 1</div>
    <button class="js-update-val" data-id="1">Обновить</button>
    <button class="js-toggle-val" data-id="1">Toggle</button>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="class-val-2" data-id="2">Val 2</div>
    <button class="js-update-val-2" data-id="2">Обновить</button>
    <button class="js-toggle-val-2" data-id="2">Toggle</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Есть родительский класс (`FirstClass`) с переменной.
Его наследует `SecondClass`.
И есть `ThirdClass`, который наследует `SecondClass`.

При инициализации переменная `flag` во всех трех классах одинаковая до тех пор, пока в каком-то из классов она не изменяется. Объясните пожалуйста, почему переменная при инициализации одна для всех, а после изменения - у каждого класса своя?

И как сделать так, чтобы данные были одни для всех потомков?

Comment: "переменная при инициализации одна для всех" - ??

Comment: Статичное свойство значит вам нужно (определённо в базовом классе). Которое, в целом, не будет относится ни к одному потомку, но выполнять будет то, что вам нужно (если это вам нужно ("чтобы данные были одни для всех потомков"))

Comment: Если кратко: вот у вас есть  родители и есть бабушка и дедушка. Родители - наследники бабушки,дедушки. Вы - наследник родителей...  У них есть глаза. И есть вы - у вас тоже есть глаза. И они и вы родились с глазами. Это общее, по логике. Правда? Но у кого-то близорукость. И у вас тоже... **Теперь вопрос**: почему если бабушка сделает операцию по улучшению зрения, то у вас тоже должно улучшиться? И наоборот

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Пример с семьей хороший, но немного не точный, я же не указываю, что в дочернем классе есть свои данные.... ))
Разбираюсь с static

Comment: Решил проблему воспользовавшись static methods
Спасибо